# SwiftUI - how to align multiline Text to left side?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to get `Text` to touch the left side. Right now, they all have unequal spacing on the sides. Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Some long text long longgggggg long long long long long long long long long long long long")
                .border(Color.blue)
            
            Text("Some long text long a long long long long long long long long long long long long")
                .border(Color.blue)
            
            Text("Some long text long asda long long long long long long long long long long long long")
                .border(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: 3 Text stacked vertically, each with different widths and centered]

This is what I want (achieved with `HStack` + `Spacer()`):

[image: 3 Text stacked vertically, each with different widths but aligned left]

How can I do this? `HStack` + `Spacer()` doesn't seem right for multiline `Text`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out as I was writing my question. Just add `alignment: .leading` to the VStack.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) { /// here!
            Text("Some long text long longgggggg long long long long long long long long long long long long")
                .border(Color.blue)

            Text("Some long text long a long long long long long long long long long long long long")
                .border(Color.blue)

            Text("Some long text long asda long long long long long long long long long long long long")
                .border(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: 3 Text stacked vertically, each with different widths but aligned left]